# How to filter and are using a function in haskell

Tags: haskell

### I have a function

```hs
f::String -> String
f (a:arr) = fa a : f arr
  where
    fa :: Char -> Char
    fa 'A' = 'T'
    fa 'T' = 'A'
    fa 'G' = 'C'
    fa 'C' = 'G'
```

The function will not work for some input, and the error is "Non-exhaustive patterns in function f."

So I want to filter an array of strings of all the elements that work with this function.

Like:

```hs
map f arr
```

So it will return only the list of elements that worked out with the function.

Comment: I recommend to keep warnings on with `-Wall`: doing so would make GHC report the case you are not handling, the empty list `[]`. Add `f [] = []`. (Also, you are not handling the other characters, perhaps using `error "not a valid ATGC input"` could do)

Answer (score 2):

You can work with [**`mapMaybe :: (a -> Maybe b) -> [a] -> [b]`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.16.3.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:mapMaybe) where `f` returns a `Just x` in case it has to perform the mapping, and `Nothing` if the input is invalid:

```
import Data.Maybe(mapMaybe)

mapRNA :: String -> String
mapRNA = mapMaybe fa
  where fa 'A' = Just 'T'
        fa 'T' = Just 'A'
        fa 'G' = Just 'C'
        fa 'C' = Just 'G'
        fa _ = Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

`String` is a bad choice for representing a sequence of bases in the first place, as there are many, many more `Char` values than there are valid bases. Start with something like `data Base = A | T | G | C deriving Show`; then

```
f :: [Base] -> [Base]
f = map g
   where g :: Base -> Base
         g A = T
         g T = A
         g G = C
         g C = G
```

If you need to, you can write a function of type `[Base] -> String` that takes advantage of the `Show` instance derived for `Base`.